# Promises to update mongoose - can I do it without specifying "resolve()"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am learning about promises and updating documents in mongoose. I have a promise that is working when I include a "resolve" argument but not without that argument, and I can't figure out how to remove it for purposes of streamlining the code. I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364899/completing-a-promise-without-reject-resolve) and [this one about .save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847852/chaining-promise-to-update-a-reference-document-in-mongoose) but still don't understand if this is possible - I am still learning the ins and outs of promises. I got it to work with a Promise.all but not a single Promise. Here is the working request:

```
function updateQuantities(){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        var conditions = {'titleByDate.instanceId'  : {$ne: null}};
        var update     = {'titleByDate.currentQuantity':  0,'titleByDate.newTitle':  0};
        resolve(titleRecords.update(conditions, update, options));
    })
}

updateQuantities().then(/*a bunch of other promises*/)
```

And this one does not work, it gives an 'unexpected token var' error:

```
function updateQuantities(){
    return new Promise(
        var conditions = {'titleByDate.instanceId'  : {$ne: null}};
        var update     = {'titleByDate.currentQuantity':  0,'titleByDate.newTitle':  0};
        return titleRecords.update(conditions, update, options);
    )
}
updateQuantities().then(/*a bunch of other promises*/)
```

Is there any way I can write the bottom one so that it works and I don't have to use resolve()? Thanks.

Comment: Does `titleRecords.update` return a promise? If so, just return that and remove the `return new Promise` wrapper.

Comment: @4castle I don't think so - tried that but it says 'then' isn't valid so i assume it doesn't return a promise

Comment: @naomik I tried cutting out the (resolve) and making it just () but then the promise doesn't seem to be resolving. What confuses me is I was above to make a set of Promise.all without ever typing 'resolve' elsewhere, so I thought there might be a way to do this.

Comment: @4castle nevermind you were totally right. I don't know what I was doing before but now it works removing that wrapper. Easy. Thanks

Comment: Yeah it's a duplicate - I just didn't find that one in my searches. Thanks

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help. I believe you can approve the duplicate if you wish to close the question.